# Upgrade-SPContentDatabase fails after installing updates

Tags: 2016, content-database, upgrade-sharepoint, windows-server-2016

After installing the latest Cumulative Update for SharePoint 2016, I tried to upgrade content database but It gives an error each time.

> 100.00% : SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content Finalizing the upgrade...
>
> Upgrade-SPContentDatabase : Invalid column name 'TS_LINE_ADDED_IN_TS'.
>   Invalid column name 'TS_LINE_ADDED_IN_TS'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Upgrade-SPContentDatabase -Identity fe2d6c65-a1d0-49cc-b154-75433ede7 ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...ContentDatabase:SPCmdletUpgradeContentDatabase)
>   [Upgrade    -SPContentDatabase], SqlException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletUpgradeContentDatabase

Have you ever faced with a like that issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try to do the following:**

- [Dismount the content database](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/dismount-spcontentdatabase?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973&view=sharepoint-ps) which has the "Invalid Column" issue.
- Run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard to get the farm patched successfully.
- [Mount the unmounted database](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sql-server-backup-restore-instead-of-a-stsadm-backup-restore-in-sharepoint-2010/) again,
- Then run the below cmdlet

  ```
  Get-SPContentDatabase –Identity WSS_Content_Name | Upgrade-SPContentDatabase
  ```

**For more details, Please Check**

- **[Database running in compatibility range and upgrade recommended](http://Database%20running%20in%20compatibility%20range%20and%20upgrade%20recommended)**
- **[Health Analyzer Issue: Product/patch installation or server upgrade required](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/product-patch-installation-or-server-upgrade-required/)**

Comment: There was a table which name is MSP_TIMESHEET_LINES and one column was missing in that table, I am not sure why it was missing but after adding this column, it is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue, you need to upgrade the content database to match the version of the rest of the farm using the PowerShell cmdlet "Upgrade-SPContentDatabase".

```
Upgrade-SPContentDatabase -Identity <database>
```